# Change password class, crypt() and comparison + checking old pass

Tags: php, cookies, crypt

Ok so i am coding away on this change password section of my site.

Please note that i am only a few weeks old in PHP.

Thats why i used md5 for password encryption before but I researched about password security and decided to use the crypt() function of PHP to hash my passwords instead of just md5 or so.

I have encountert a problem with my previous change password function, where the usersession was aborted after saving the new password into the database which resulted in the user being logged out. Old password change site for reference: http://pastebin.com/hf6WhtEQ

My initial approach was to use `session_regenerate_id()` to update the session because it seemed that simply updating the password in the cookie didn't work.

The approach seemed to work at first but then upon further testing it was clear that it was useless.

So i started again from scratch and created my following code.

I didnt implement the cookie yet as i am still unsure how to go about it and want to make sure i have strong password security first before i set new cookies.

Now my plan looks like this:

1. I check if the user is logged in and the owner of the account.
2. I want to check if the password in the database matches the password in `$oldpass`.
3. I want to compare `$newpass` and `$repeatpass`, if both passwords match then i want to crypt `$newpass` using `crypt()`.
4. Finally i want to update the database with the new crypted password and also update the cookie with the new pass, while making sure that the user stays logged in.

Now, my question are:

1. Why do i keep getting the message "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back" even though the header clearly has the username in it.
2. How can i bring everything in a well ordered fashion where everything executes according to my plan. (right now its kind of unordered and im not sure what the correct order of the if statements etc. should be).

change_pass.php :

```
    <?php

    include 'check_login_status.php';

    $u="";
    $oldpass=md5("");
    //stripping both strings of white spaces
    $newpass = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['newpass']);
    $repeatpass = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['repeatpass']);

    //get the username from the header
    if(isset($_GET["u"])){
        $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    } else {
        header("location: compare_pass.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
        exit(); 
    }

    // Select the member from the users table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password='$oldpass' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    // Now make sure that user exists in the table
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
    if($numrows < 1){
        echo "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back";
        exit(); 
    }

    $isOwner = "no";
    //check if user is logged in owner of account
    if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true){
        $isOwner = "yes";
    }

    $passhash = "";

    if (($newpass) === ($repeatpass)) {
            $passhash = crypt_sha256("$newpass", "B-Pz=0%5mI~SAOcW0pMUdgKQh1_B7H6sbKAl+9~O98E9MBPrpGOtE65ro~8R");
        } else {
            echo "comparison failed! :(";
        }

    //  
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]) &&($isOwner == "yes") &&($user_ok == true) &&($newpass) === ($repeatpass)) {

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET `password`='$passhash' WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    }
?>

<h3>Create new password</h3>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div>Current Password</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="oldpass" >
    <div>New Password</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="newpass" >
    <div>Repeat Password</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="repeatpass" >
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    <p id="status" ></p>
  </form>
```

check_login_status.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db_conx.php");
// Files that inculde this file at the very top would NOT require 
// connection to database or session_start(), be careful.
// Initialize some vars
$user_ok = false;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";
// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
    $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_conx,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    if($user_ok == true){
        // Update their lastlogin datetime field
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Everybody would really benefit if you trimmed this question down a bit. You're asking four different questions about three screens full of code with a preamble which seems mostly irrelevant and incomprehensible. It's really hard to get useful answers this way. Ask one question at a time, if at all.

Comment: Yea its true, its alot of input to answer, i just thought it would be better to keep everything contained in one post instead of splitting everything up and risking penalty for asking too many questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have their old pass when they're logging in, because they need to provide it to you in cleartext when they login. If this is the case, why don't you just pull both passwords out of the database (old and new). If it's the old pass, md5 it, and if it's equal store the new crypted password (Based on what they entered) into the database (Along with clearing out the old pass), and if it's the new pass, then compare via your new crypt method.

Also, on a side note, since we're talking about security. [Bind your parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of putting them in your code like that! This practically eliminates the possibility of sql injection and allows you to not have to run regex against all your inputs.

Comment: I thought it would be better to not really pull the password from the database for security reasons and instead compare the old password that will be provided by the user with the one stored in the database. Wouldn't it be dangerous to get the password from the database into the code?

Comment: Not really. They're already providing their password in clear text in the $_POST array, so I don't see why pulling encrypted passwords from the db and comparing them via php would be an issue.

Comment: Okay thanks for your advice, I will then use your aproach to compare the old passwords.

Comment: This also eliminates the need for a password reset screen! Makes for a better end user experience.

Comment: I am planning on expanding this site to give the user the ability to change the user data in the database. Do you mean an extra site to change their password?

Answer (score 0):

Several things occur to me with your approach.
Firstly you mention encrption of the password using crypt. That is one way hashing of the data and not really encryption. Within php and mysql there are built in functions for proper encryption - meaning passwords can be decrypted if necessary but are stored securely. Hashing routines, such as MD5 are not secure and have been broken so a more robust approach would be to encrypt the passwords using a 256cipher and an a very complex key.

For instance, in mysql:

```
aes_encrypt('password','complex key') /*to encrypt*/
aes_decrypt( '<encrypted pwd>,'complex key' ) /*to decrypt*/
```

Second: To agree with Danbopes above, bindParams virtually eliminates sql injection attacks which has to be a good thing.

Thridly: You mention storing the password in the cookie - even in a hashed form. This is a very bad idea and is something to avoid. What if an attacker intercepted that cookie?

Finally - mysqli is good but PDO is, to my mind, a better alternative - but that is probably just a personal choice.

Comment: Great input! Thank you for that. Then instead of the password i think i should store some other data from the user in the cookie. thats a really good point. As i am still new i just went with some tutorials which used mysqli and i decided to learn pdo later as its alot more sophisticated and able to use all databases i thought it would be too difficult for me to learn as a beginner.